# cannot start mozilla using custom profile in karateUI

Tags: ssl-certificate, karate, geckodriver

I'm using karate 1.3.0 and I'm stuck trying to launch mozilla Firefox v105.0.2 using a specific SSL client certificate.
As a mention, I developed this scenario before, successfuly using Java + Selenium, but now I need to integrate UI functional tests in my API test suite that is using Karate.

I wrote this code:

```
  Scenario: 
    * def session = {'capabilities': {'alwaysMatch': {'acceptInsecureCerts':true, 'moz:firefoxOptions': {'profile': 'classpath:FFProfile/ste7rob0.zip.b64','log': {'level': 'debug'}}}}}
    * def driverConfig = { type: 'geckodriver', showBrowserLog: true, showProcessLog: true, showDriverLog: true, executable: './src/test/resources/driver/mozilla/win64/geckodriver.exe'}
    * driverConfig.webDriverSession = session
    * configure driver = driverConfig
    Given driver monitorUrl
```

And I was expecting to get a webdriver to access monitorUrl using the profile specified. The profile folder was customized manually, zipped and encoded to base64 on the development machine.
But the result was:

```
18:20:16.267 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - http response code: 500, response: {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Invalid byte 58, offset 9.","stacktrace":""}}, request: POST http://localhost:4444/session
18:20:16.268 [main] ERROR c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - webdriver session create status 500, {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Invalid byte 58, offset 9.","stacktrace":""}}
18:20:16.269 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: webdriver session create status 500, {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Invalid byte 58, offset 9.","stacktrace":""}}, options: {type=geckodriver, showBrowserLog=true, showProcessLog=true, showDriverLog=true, executable=./src/test/resources/driver/mozilla/win64/geckodriver.exe, webDriverSession={capabilities={alwaysMatch={acceptInsecureCerts=true, moz:firefoxOptions={profile=classpath:FFProfile/ste7rob0.zip.b64, log={level=debug}}}}}, target=null}
java.lang.RuntimeException: webdriver session create status 500, {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Invalid byte 58, offset 9.","stacktrace":""}}
    at com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.<init>(WebDriver.java:67)
    at com.intuit.karate.driver.firefox.GeckoWebDriver.<init>(GeckoWebDriver.java:42)
    at com.intuit.karate.driver.firefox.GeckoWebDriver.start(GeckoWebDriver.java:48)
    at com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.start(DriverOptions.java:316)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.driver(ScenarioEngine.java:881)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScenarioActions.driver(ScenarioActions.java:426)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.StepRuntime.execute(StepRuntime.java:296)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.execute(ScenarioRuntime.java:449)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.run(ScenarioRuntime.java:400)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.processScenario(FeatureRuntime.java:199)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioIterator.tryAdvance(ScenarioIterator.java:162)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:332)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:706)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.run(FeatureRuntime.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.SyncExecutorService.execute(SyncExecutorService.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at com.intuit.karate.Suite.run(Suite.java:237)
    at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:496)
    at com.intuit.karate.cli.IdeMain.main(IdeMain.java:60)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
18:20:16.270 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/splmonitor/TC3.acces_autorizat.feature:12
Given driver monitorUrl
driver config / start failed: webdriver session create status 500, {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Invalid byte 58, offset 9.","stacktrace":""}}, options: {type=geckodriver, showBrowserLog=true, showProcessLog=true, showDriverLog=true, executable=./src/test/resources/driver/mozilla/win64/geckodriver.exe, webDriverSession={capabilities={alwaysMatch={acceptInsecureCerts=true, moz:firefoxOptions={profile=classpath:FFProfile/ste7rob0.zip.b64, log={level=debug}}}}}, target=null}
src/test/java/splmonitor/TC3.acces_autorizat.feature:12
18:20:16.270 [geckodriver_1674836415732] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [C:\QA\workspace2022\aliaspay-test-engine\.\src\test\resources\driver\mozilla\win64\geckodriver.exe, --port=4444] working dir: target\geckodriver_1674836415732
```

Comment: I have no idea, so I will pass.  I don't know of anyone trying this with karate. would be great if you can do some research and contribute findings back. from the error message it seems that the ZIP / profile did not work, so try without a profile and see if you can confirm that. open-source contributions are *most* welcome